# For loop to write pdf in R

Tags: r, for-loop, pdf

I would like to create a R code which writes me 50 times a pdf but adjusts the name of the pdf fromy mypdf1.pdf to mypdf50.pdf. Is this possible using a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible. Here is some simple code to create 50 blank PDF's names according to the specified using `paste0`. And you can then fill the PDFs with what ever in the loop, or create additional loops

```
 setwd()
 
 for (i in 1:50) {    pdf(paste0("mypdf", i, ".pdf"))
   
    dev.off() }
```